# php simplexml node no longer exists : how to get attribute value?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

After wasting more than 6 hour, I'm posting my problem here.

I'm trying to get simplexmlelement attribute value :

This is my var_dump value :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
 ["@attributes"]=>
 array(3) {
 ["type"]=>
string(4) "Rich"
["template"]=>
string(44) "EntityContainer.HeroGeneric_8_1_RTM-7814aaaa"
["disambiguationId"]=>
string(36) "85fa63d3-9596-adb9-b4eb-502273d84f56"
 }
}
```

I want to get ["type"] value "Rich". However i am not able to get that. I've seen a lot of answers and code example before post it here but they did not help.
Actually first time i am trying to use simplexmlelement [Advance code]

My php code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml2 = $xml->channel->item;

foreach ($xml2 as $out_ns) 
{ 

$ns = $out_ns->getNamespaces(true); 
$child = $out_ns->children($ns['win']);

var_dump($child); // Value is written above simple xml object

print_r((string) $child->attributes());

}
```

I want to know what's wrong i have done. I want to achieve type and disambiguationId attribute values.

Error:

> **Warning**:  SimpleXMLElement::__toString(): Node no longer exists in **E:\xampp\htdocs\ring\dom.php** on line **15**

Please check my code help me.

Comment: what is the structure of your XML?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if element exists:

```
if($child &&  $child->attributes()) {
   print_r($child->attributes());
}
```